# Efficient algorithm for finding multi-source children in a DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, children, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a DAG and multiple sources `S1 .. Sn`, we define a valid node as a node that is reachable from all sources. Find out all the valid nodes which don't have a valid parent.

Effectively, find the *direct-multi-source children* of `S1 .. Sn`

---

Example: In the following DAG, `S1, S2, S3` are the sources. Nodes `a, b, c` are reachable via all sources. However, node `c` has a parent which is also reachable via all sources.

So the top view is `a, b`

[image: example DAG]

---

The naive algorithm for this would be to

1. For each source, find the set of reachable nodes
2. Take the intersection of these sets to find all valid nodes
3. Perform a multi-source BFS from all sources. When moving from `parent -> child` keep track of whether the parent was a valid node or not. Any valid node which was reached via a parent which is also a valid node gets discarded.

This algorithm takes O(`(V+E) * S`) time because of step 1.

```
V = number of vertices
E = number of edges
S = number of sources
```

---

Is there a faster algorithm? Can this be done in O(`V+E`)?

Comment: To fix step 1, you need to perform a multi-source BFS where a node is not added to the queue until all of its incoming edges have been explored. So the node above `a` (which we'll call `x`) doesn't get added to the queue until it has been reached from both S1 and S3. Then node `b` doesn't get added to the queue until it's been reached from `x` and S2. At that point, it is known that `b` is valid, and any nodes that are children of `b` are discarded.

Comment: Problems like this were of intense interest for dataflow calculations in compilers. I don't think a really satisfactory solution of the kind that you're seeking was ever found. It might be profitable to replace (e.g.) 64 of those DFSes in Step 1 with a single data-parallel topological traversal, but a priori, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do this in O(V+E) time if you can union sets of size S in constant time.

In the easy case, you would use bitmasks to represent sets, so if S <= 64, for example, then you're good with using a 64-bit word to represent each set, and bitwise-OR for union.

Even if you have a lot more than 64 sources, a compressed set representation with an algorithm like this one is probably going to be your best bet.

The algorithm isn't difficult:

1. Topologically sort the graph, using Kahn's algorithm of DFS;
2. Initialize a set for each vertex.  Sources get singleton sets containing only themselves, and other vertexes get empty sets.  Also initialize each vertex as "not marked" and "not crossed out";
3. Process the vertexes in topological order. For each vertex, if it's "crossed out", then cross out all of its children.  Otherwise replace its set with the union of its set and the sets of all of its parents (which have already been processed).  If its set then contains all sources, then mark the vertex and cross out all of its children (which have not yet been processed).
4. Return all the vertexes that are marked.

Comment: Thanks. This will work. One caveat of this algo is that it is in-elegant when S is a singleton. If S is a singleton, the direct children of S is the answer. This algo will process the entire DAG for that trivial case. Although we can handle that case separately, I'm wondering if there is a way that begins the search from the sources - thus excluding all the nodes that are come topologically before all of the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 can be optimized.

```
SET T = valid nodes from step 2
LOOP V over valid nodes
   LOOP P over valid node's parents
      IF P is valid
          DELETE V from T
```

T is the set of "top nodes"

Answer (score 0):

You can "distribute" the data structures by searching from each source in order to label each vertex with the set of sources that reach it. Nodes where the set's cardinality is equal the number of sources are valid. Make a set V of these. Then make one more search of the whole graph removing vertices reached via a valid parent from V. At the end, V contains the answer.

The run time will I think be be O(V * E) assuming constant time set insert and remove. This algorithm takes set intersection out of the picture at the possible cost of more memory.

Comment: Thanks. Matt posted a similar algorithm that has better runtime if S is small. O(V*E) is much worse than O(V+E). If S is small compared to V, then it is also worse than O((V+E)*S).

Comment: Matt's solution relies on unit time set intersection, which is basically cheating. That's the reason Is suggested this algorithm.